# QT intellisense question

Tags: qt4

in this code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Button Text");
    QObject::connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),&app,SLOT(quit()));
    button->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

intellisense is appearing when the cursor is in SIGNAL parenthesis to write **button** event. But it doesn't appear in SLOT parenthesis to write **app** method ?

is it related with **&** character in front of **app** ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I felt so silly.

```
QObject::connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),&app,SLOT(quit()));
```

quit() or intellisense doesn't appear because any function could be written between parenthesis.